# Count values in SharePoint list and update separate list with count using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, count, update-items

I have a list in SharePoint called "List" that lists projects with their status. The Status column choices are Not started, At Risk, and Complete. I have another list called "Graph List" that has two columns: Status and Count. The status column in "Graph List" contains rows for Not started, At Risk, and Complete.

I would like to create a flow that:

1. Counts the number projects with each status (Not Started, At Risk, Complete) in "List", and
2. Updates the count of projects in each status from "List" in the Count column of "Graph List"

I have been able to get the flow to count the number of Complete projects (so far I'm only testing with one count), however I am unable to create the correct Update Items action to update the Graph List. I am new to Power Automate. Can someone help with the correct flow to count all statuses and update them in the Graph List? Thank you.

[image: lists]

Answer (score 0):

What part of the update are you having issues with?

If you store each of the counts into their own variables in the flow, then you should be able to use a "Get Items" Sharepoint action to return all the items in your Graph List.

Then you can use a "Switch" that looks at your Status Column with a Case for each of your statuses. Then use "Update Item" Sharepoint Action in each of your 3 cases that use the appropriate stored count variables.

The rough concept is below, replacing title with "Status" in the switch. If you need more in depth screenshots I could look at mocking up an exact scenario for you.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this info. If you're still able to send screenshots of an exact mockup, that would be extremely helpful as I'm very new to PA and may still have issues trying to create the flow. Thank you.